# An infinity-category is a functor, but is it a category in some way and is the simplex notions so universal?

Tags: category-theory, simplicial-stuff, higher-category-theory

For some time I had the impression that infinity-categories are just a generalization of higher order categories: categories whose arrows have arrows among them, and they have further arrows etc. Essentially – every category should be an infinity-category, possibly “degenerate”, because arrows-among-arrows end to exists anymore at some sufficiently high $n$. I imagined that I could take any category and add arrows-among-arrows and get a higher or even infinity-category. Similarly, I could take any infinity-category, delete some arrows-among-arrows and get a lower order category.

But I am now trying to study this subject using [“Introduction to Infinity-Categories” by Markus Land](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-030-61524-6) and it gives such definition:

> A simplicial set is called an $∞$-category if it has the extension property for all inner horn inclusions $\Lambda^n_j \to \Delta_n$, $n ≥ 2$, $0 < j < n$.

A simplicial set, by definition, is a functor which assigns to every ordered set of numbers $[0, \dotsc, n]$ a set of $n$-simplices (possibly, degenerate) $X_n = \{ [0, 0, 0, \dotsc], [0, 1, 2, 2, \dotsc] \}$. It describes some simplicial complex and of course, there exists special unions of faces, called horns and they can be mapped to $n$-simplices in this complex. That is fine.

But I cannot grasp – where is the category in this definition of infinity-category? How is this functor a category as well?

And is there a correspondence between the two notions of higher-order/infinity-categories which we have – 1) the intuitive one as a category with arrows-among-arrows; 2) the exact one – as simplicial set?

Comment: Look at a construction called the nerve of a category:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nerve_(category_theory)#:~:text=Nerve%20%28category%20theory%29%20In%20category%20theory%2C%20a%20discipline,called%20the%20classifying%20space%20of%20the%20category%20C.

Also look at Kerodon. Kerodon outlines the relation between 1-categories and $\infty$-catogories via the nerve construction.

Comment: Also I would say this: I originally found the definition of $\infty$-categories in terms of simplical sets a bit odd. But it is important to remember that simplical sets and quasi-categories are just one model (among many) of $\infty$-categories. Thus a simplicial set (with the inner horn property) is just a way to present $\infty$-categories. By working more with this model, you will find that it does indeed encode the desired properties of $\infty$-categories.

Comment: So, it should be possible: I can start with any category, add arrows-among-arrows and then I could construct the simplicial-set-model for any such higher-order category, I can do some proofs, theorem proving in this simplicial-set-model and then I can bring back those results to my initial category with arrows-among-arrows. This conversion between category and simplicial-set-model and back it via nerve construction... OK, I will check this...

Comment: the problem is that the phrase you keep using, "arrows between arrows", is not precise. And, in fact, as you go up in dimension, the boundary of arrows becomes increasingly complex and harder to describe. The simplical set model (and other model in different ways) is finding a way to make this imprecise phrase precise enough that we can prove theorems, ect. Also, we do not usually "start with a 1-category and add arrows between arrows". Read about the nerve construction first, its not clear to me it does what you think it does (I can't really understand what you think it does).

Comment: Also, I should add, simplical sets model $(\infty,1)$-categories. So all higher arrows are actually invertible. So we don't quite have "arrows between arrows" all the way up. Rather, we have 1-arrows and then homotopies between 1-arrows and homotopies between homotopies. I suggest working through something like Kerodon and you will get a sense for how these things behave. Its hard to see the forest through the trees before spending time with simplicial sets (in my experience).